# how to make a 2-column responsive system using ionic

Tags: css, ionic-framework, ionic2, ionic3

I want to make a 2-column responsive system. I want the badge (2) to have a column of the exact size of the content of it and the column (1) has the space it deserves. how can I do it? This is my code:[image]

```
    <ion-grid no-padding>
        <ion-row>
          <ion-col col-10>
            <h4 >
              <strong>{{ antecedentAlert.antPac.get_tipo_antecedente.nombre }}</strong>
              <span *ngIf="antecedentAlert.antPac.get_subtipo_antecedente != null">
                : {{ antecedentAlert.antPac.get_subtipo_antecedente.nombre }}
              </span>
                .
                .
                .
          </ion-col>
          <ion-col col-auto>
            <span class="contenedor-badge-icon">
              <ion-badge class="badge-estado-ant" color="azul-2" *ngIf="antecedentAlert.antPac.validado == 'validado' ">Validado</ion-badge>
                <ion-badge class="badge-estado-ant" color="danger" *ngIf="antecedentAlert.antPac.validado == 'no validado' ">No validado</ion-badge>
                <ion-badge class="badge-estado-ant" color="naranja-2" *ngIf="antecedentAlert.antPac.validado == 'pendiente' "><ion-icon class="candado-antecedentes" [name]="antecedentAlert.antPac.privado=='1'?'lock':''" [color]="white"></ion-icon>  Por validar</ion-badge>
            </span>
          </ion-col>
        </ion-row>
      </ion-grid>
```

Actual result:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Change `col-10` of column 1 to `col-12 col-sm`.

Comment: Thank you very much, but I would like to understand it with the ionic grid. I want to make it responsive

Comment: How do you want it to behave if you want it to be responsive?

Comment: I tried to reproduce my problem in this example, I would appreciate it if you can help me. https://stackblitz.com/edit/ionic-wdofnx?file=pages/home/home.html  I want the first column to take the remaining space, and column 2 to be the exact size according to its content. for what? I want to make it possible to optimize the space on small screen mobile devices.

Comment: So you want column1 to take the remaining space (as if col-12) when column2 go down?

Answer (score 0):

What you need to do is replace `col-10` for `col-xs-10`. When there's no breakpoint specified Ionic'll fallback to `sm` breakpoint, whose by default is `(min-width: 576px)`, so that's why your grid breaks to a second row when in a small viewport device. This way the `col-auto` of your badges column will work perfectly.

Hope this helps.

Comment: thanks! do you see my example on stackblitz.com/edit/ionic-wdofnx?file=pages/home/home.html  ? hablo español

Comment: Yes i've seen and used your example to find a solution, here it is https://stackblitz.com/edit/ionic-ogpdoc?embed=1&file=pages/home/home.html, sorry but i don't speak spanish :(